# Is the sudo bless --mount command in macOS deprecated. If so, what is in use now?

Tags: terminal, command-line, startup, unix, mount

After installing some other operating system like Linux, I would use some version of the `sudo bless --mount` command like

```
$ sudo bless --mount /Volumes/EFI --setboot --file /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
```

to make macOS the default boot system again.

While the command still works, I was wondering if the `sudo bless --mount` command has been deprecated like some articles say it has.

- https://krypted.com/mac-security/dont-use-bless-to-change-startup-disks-any-more-in-os-x/
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7740130

If it has, then what should I be using as a replacement command for making macOS the default boot method again?

Comment: What articles said it was deprecated? Can you post it to your question?

Comment: https://krypted.com/mac-security/dont-use-bless-to-change-startup-disks-any-more-in-os-x/ as well as https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7740130
these being user generated articles mind you. I can't speak for the validity of them.

Comment: I just want to confirm the facts and know what's what. Fake news and all. @Allan

The exchange of stacks has never lie to me. My attempts at using the acclaimed ``systemsetup commands`` have not faired well.

Comment: If you want to change the default operating system to boot from the command line with System Integrity Protection (SIP) enabled, then you have to install another Startup Manager. For example, [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

Comment: No, the first article doesn't claim `bless` is deprecated, despite the alarming clickbait title; it only gives one author's (not at all convincing) opinion (without solid justification) that they think `systemsetup <subcommands>` are preferable to using `bless`. And the second post is only complaining that the name of the boot volume isn't always "Macintosh HD"; this isn't important either.

Answer (score 4):

No.  There is nothing (that I could find) from Apple indicating that `bless` has been deprecated.

The two articles you posted:

- [Don’t Use bless To Change Startup Disks Any More In OS X](https://krypted.com/mac-security/dont-use-bless-to-change-startup-disks-any-more-in-os-x/)
- [Setboot? Formerly bless? Command line OS switching?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7740130)

are a blogger's opinion about what to use instead of `bless` and a thread in an Apple Discussion forum in which a random person is asking the same question; the articles are from July 15th, 2015 and November 8th 2016 respectively.  Needless to say, they are woefully out of date.

This does serve as a opportunity, however to highlight an important factor:  Apple won't deprecate something (especially as critical as `bless`) without notifying the public about it (i.e. in the release notes, updated man pages, etc.)

Why?  Well, how would devs and sys admins be aware of the changes and begin planning their transitions?

**Deprecation notifications will come from Apple, not random people opining on the Internet**.

Comment: Gracias me amigo, just checking on these things. Fake news is the reality we live in.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I saw your question and it surprised me a bit so I had to go research...